# Is it acceptable to use Thread.sleep in this case - Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not sure if I am misusing Thread.sleep

I have some tests within my framework which are parametrized and for every test when i tear down(call driver.quit())...and then re initiate for the next test am getting this Error
--Session ID is null...Running tests after calling quit()!

Hence I introduced Thread.sleep() before re-initiating the tests and this solved the problem.But Am I misusing the Sleep here? Your answers would be helpful!

thanks

Comment: Are you using JUnit or some other framework to write your test-cases and execute your tests? If you aren't, just move the call to `driver.quit()` after the last test. If you are, there are ways to call methods after all tests are executed. For JUnit: `@AfterClass public void afterAllTests() {driver.quit();}`

Answer (score 0):

The call to `driver.quit()` closes the browser and end the Selenium driver itself, that's why you get the exception the next time you want to access the driver.

We used JUnit for our Selenium tests and used the `@beforeClass` and `@afterClass` parts to setup and shutdown Selenium. So every test class used it's own browser session, and all tests within that class shared the same one.
`@beforeClass` was also the part where we opend the page and logged in and did an initial login-successful-validation assertion.

Comment: You should specify that your solution is based on the JUnit framework. These annotation are part of the JUnit framework, they are not part of Selenium, and the OP never told he was using it

Comment: Your right, I updated my post and stated, that we uses JUnit.